How do I create/delete files on SMB server while connected remotely from iPhone via NordVPN Meshnet?
I'm connecting to an Ubuntu server SMB share from an iPhone via Files app remotely using NordVPN Meshnet IP address.
I figured out how to make it work, but I cannot create or delete files once I'm connected to the server.
I tried using all the commands to give permissions to the SMB user after adding the SMB user to the operating system user group and using all the different smb.conf file configurations that I could. I also tried to share a file in the directory /srv instead of the /home/user directory.
Here is the smb.conf file configurations I added and tried:
[Server]
comment = Server
path = /home/user
browsable = yes
writable = yes
valid users = user
create mask = 0777
force create mode = 0777
valid users = @user
write list = @user
force group = user
directory mask = 0777
hosts allow = ALL


Please update question with which version of Ubuntu you're using. Also, please provide any commands you used in your attempt to solve the issue.

try ''guest ok = yes''
